# How to fetch data from MySQL database into Excel

Tags: mysql, excel

How to fetch data from MySQL database table into Excel?

Comment: are you talking about exporting to excel???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server is also your client machine you can do

```
select * from table1 into outfile 'c:/path/outfile.csv'
```

*(Note the use of forward slashes even on Windows)*

If your server is a remote machine, make sure your have the MySQL client software installed on the client machine and do:

```
mysql -e "SELECT * from table1" > file_name
```

You can then open the csv file in Excel.

Answer (score 8):

1. Install [`Connector/ODBC`](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)
2. Create an `ODBC DSN` (`Control Panel / Administration / ODBC` if on Windows)
3. Import data using `Microsoft Query` (`Data / External Data / From Other Sources / Microsoft Query` in `Excel 2007`)

Answer (score 2):

Try out with

```
SELECT column1, column1, column1 from tablename INTO OUTFILE "path/CSV/tablename.xls" FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" <br>
```

refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is ODBC. You can download the [ODBC driver for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) (if you don't have it already). Then, once inside Excel, you can go to "Data-> Obtain external data" (the name and location of the menu items may vary) and pick or create a data source.

Answer (score 0):

odbc-query.

excel: /data/get external data...